# pydantic package ImportError (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

Tags: pydantic

my system: macos Ventura 13.0
CPU: AppleM2
python: 3.10.0

heroku: heroku/7.67.1 darwin-x64 node-v14.19.0
pydantic: 1.10.2

when i run command "heroku local web", i got the error, apple m2 is ARM arch, why the error is "need x86_64"? if someone meet the problem, how can i fix it?

```
9:19:25 PM web.1 |      from fastapi import params
9:19:25 PM web.1 |    File "/Users/wj/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fuse-hotel-MQQZRb-z-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/params.py", line 4, in <module>
9:19:25 PM web.1 |      from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo, Undefined
9:19:25 PM web.1 |  ImportError: dlopen(/Users/wj/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fuse-hotel-MQQZRb-z-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/wj/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fuse-hotel-MQQZRb-z-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/wj/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fuse-hotel-M
9:19:25 PM web.1 |  >  QQZRb-z-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Users/wj/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fuse-hotel-MQQZRb-z-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
9:19:25 PM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

poetry show:

```
alembic            1.8.1     A database migration tool for SQLAlchemy.
amqp               5.1.1     Low-level AMQP client for Python (fork of amqplib).
anyio              3.6.2     High level compatibility layer for multiple asynchronous event loop implementations
asgiref            3.5.2     ASGI specs, helper code, and adapters
async-timeout      4.0.2     Timeout context manager for asyncio programs
asyncpg            0.27.0    An asyncio PostgreSQL driver
attrs              22.1.0    Classes Without Boilerplate
billiard           3.6.4.0   Python multiprocessing fork with improvements and bugfixes
black              22.12.0   The uncompromising code formatter.
celery             5.2.7     Distributed Task Queue.
certifi            2022.12.7 Python package for providing Mozilla's CA Bundle.
click              8.1.3     Composable command line interface toolkit
click-didyoumean   0.3.0     Enables git-like *did-you-mean* feature in click
click-plugins      1.1.1     An extension module for click to enable registering CLI commands via setuptools entry-points.
click-repl         0.2.0     REPL plugin for Click
fastapi            0.86.0    FastAPI framework, high performance, easy to learn, fast to code, ready for production
fastapi-camelcase  1.0.5     Package provides an easy way to have camelcase request/response bodies for Pydantic
flake8             3.9.2     the modular source code checker: pep8 pyflakes and co
gevent             22.10.2   Coroutine-based network library
greenlet           2.0.1     Lightweight in-process concurrent programming
h11                0.14.0    A pure-Python, bring-your-own-I/O implementation of HTTP/1.1
httpcore           0.16.2    A minimal low-level HTTP client.
httptools          0.5.0     A collection of framework independent HTTP protocol utils.
httpx              0.23.1    The next generation HTTP client.
idna               3.4       Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA)
iniconfig          1.1.1     iniconfig: brain-dead simple config-ini parsing
kombu              5.2.4     Messaging library for Python.
mako               1.2.4     A super-fast templating language that borrows the best ideas from the existing templating languages.
markupsafe         2.1.1     Safely add untrusted strings to HTML/XML markup.
mccabe             0.6.1     McCabe checker, plugin for flake8
mypy-extensions    0.4.3     Experimental type system extensions for programs checked with the mypy typechecker.
packaging          22.0      Core utilities for Python packages
pathspec           0.10.3    Utility library for gitignore style pattern matching of file paths.
platformdirs       2.6.0     A small Python package for determining appropriate platform-specific dirs, e.g. a "user data dir".
pluggy             1.0.0     plugin and hook calling mechanisms for python
prompt-toolkit     3.0.36    Library for building powerful interactive command lines in Python
pycodestyle        2.7.0     Python style guide checker
pycountry          22.3.5    ISO country, subdivision, language, currency and script definitions and their translations
pydantic           1.10.2    Data validation and settings management using python type hints
pyflakes           2.3.1     passive checker of Python programs
pyhumps            3.8.0       Convert strings (and dictionary keys) between snake case, camel case and pascal case in Python. Inspired by Humps for Node
pytest             7.2.0     pytest: simple powerful testing with Python
python-dotenv      0.21.0    Read key-value pairs from a .env file and set them as environment variables
python-json-logger 2.0.4     A python library adding a json log formatter
pytz               2022.6    World timezone definitions, modern and historical
pyyaml             6.0       YAML parser and emitter for Python
redis              4.4.0     Python client for Redis database and key-value store
rfc3986            1.5.0     Validating URI References per RFC 3986
setuptools         65.6.3    Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
six                1.16.0    Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
sniffio            1.3.0     Sniff out which async library your code is running under
sqlalchemy         1.4.45    Database Abstraction Library
starlette          0.20.4    The little ASGI library that shines.
typing-extensions  4.4.0     Backported and Experimental Type Hints for Python 3.7+
uvicorn            0.19.0    The lightning-fast ASGI server.
uvloop             0.17.0    Fast implementation of asyncio event loop on top of libuv
vine               5.0.0     Promises, promises, promises.
watchfiles         0.18.1    Simple, modern and high performance file watching and code reload in python.
wcwidth            0.2.5     Measures the displayed width of unicode strings in a terminal
websockets         10.4      An implementation of the WebSocket Protocol (RFC 6455 & 7692)
zope-event         4.6       Very basic event publishing system
zope-interface     5.5.2     Interfaces for Python
```

i execute the code:

```
python3 -c "import pydantic.utils; print(pydantic.utils.version_info())"
```

output:

```
pydantic version: 1.10.2
            pydantic compiled: True
                 install path: /Users/wj/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fuse-hotel-MQQZRb-z-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic
               python version: 3.11.0 (v3.11.0:deaf509e8f, Oct 24 2022, 14:43:23) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
                     platform: macOS-13.0-arm64-arm-64bit
     optional deps. installed: ['dotenv', 'typing-extensions']
```